# Switch General MIDI instruments from device? (Roland Sound Canvas, Reaper)

Tags: midi, daw, vst, cockos-reaper

I have an Swissonic EasyKey61 MIDI keyboard, and it is connected to the VST plugin "Roland Sound Canvas" via Reaper.

I am wondering how sound banks/instruments (e.g. "Piano 1", "Piccolo", "Tinkle Bell", ...; i.e. those available in the VST plugin) can be changed using input from my MIDI keyboard.

In the VST's menu, I selected "Param" --> "MIDI link" --> "Program Change", but nothing seems to change (I don't know how this option knows about which input knob, button, ... on the device I'd like to assign). Also, I tried "MIDI learn" from the menu, but this also does not seem to change anything.

Does anyone have an idea how to switch between the sound banks using my MIDI device?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to remap anything. The EasyKey can send bank change and program change messages with the `BANK MSB`, `BANK LSB`, and `PROG` keys in edit mode (see page 12/13 of the manual - [link to PDF](https://images.thomann.de/pics/atg/atgdata/document/manual/c_337438_337441_337442_r3_en_online.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sending `Program Change` instructions with the EasyKey:

- press `Edit`
- press the key which is labeled `Prog`
- enter another program number using the keyboard keys
- press the key labeled `Enter`
- press the Edit button again.